# How do you refer to this Term in English?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, translation-request

How do you refer to this theorem in English exactly?

$$a\mathbb Z+ b\mathbb Z =d\mathbb Z \text{, where }d = \gcd(a,b) \text{ and a, b}\in \mathbb Z$$

I imagine it should be something like:
"The set of all integer linear combinations is..."

Regards

Comment: "The sum of two principal ideals is the principal ideal of the greatest common divisor."

Comment: Note: @ThomasAndrews's statement requires hypotheses, such as being in a PID, else the gcd may not exist.

Comment: True, I was implicitly assuming the statement was about the integers.

Comment: Since it is tagged "elementary number theory", can we assume that you cannot use ideal-theoretic language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If restricted to elementary number theory (as tagged). I would write "the set of all integral linear combinations of $\,a,b\,$ equals the set of all integral multiples of their gcd", whose element-wise form is widely referred to as [Bezout's identity for the gcd.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezout%27s_identity)

More elementarily, I would say that any common divisor $\,c\,$ of $\,a,b\,$ of *linear* form $\,c = ja+kb,\,$ $\,j,k\in\Bbb Z,\,$ is necessarily a *greatest* common divisor, since $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid ja+kb = c,\,$ so $\,d\le c.$

Answer (score 1):

It's *called* Bézout's identity.

The most elementary way of saying it is to use the phrase *integer combination*: "the set of all integer combinations of $a$ and $b$ is the set of multiples of $\gcd(a, b)$".